# SSRS - Include Exclude data using a parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Dataset that has a field called [Operations class code]. I want to set up a parameter to include [Operations class code] using true or false. When the user clicks true, then the [Operations class code] is included but when false still shows the rest of the data.

I tried making the parameter but when I click true or false it will only show data that have [Operations class code] and then click false it will not show anything.

I deleted the parameter and then everything shows up again.

I feel like I'm missing something but I can't seem to find it.

Here is some of my where clause

`WHERE [Date] >= @StartDate AND [Date] <= @StartDate AND  [field3code] IN (@fieldcode3) AND  [field4code] <> (@showfield4)`

^^That works but don't know how to add the 5th parameter to include/exclude

EDIT:

This is what I have right now

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
SET @StartDate = @parStartDate

SELECT
[WO Number],
[WO Description],
[Work Type],
[Work Type Code],
[WO Asset Desc],
[Supervisor],
[Supervisor Code],
[Week Of],
[Cost Center Code],
[Cost Center],
[WO Priority],
[Operations Coord Class Code],
[Operations Coord Class],


SUM([Scheduled Hours]) [Scheduled Hours],
MIN([Scheduled Date]) [Date Scheduled]

FROM
    Scheduled_Work 

WHERE [Scheduled Date]>=@StartDate AND 
[Scheduled Date]<=@ThroughDate AND
[Cost Center Code] IN (@CostCenter) AND  
[Work Type Code] <>@ShowPM
```

Am I messing up something? Also I want to add that I have 3 other datasets. 1 for the Cost Center, 1 for Work Type, and then 1 for Operations Coord Class.
Do you think it might be filtering them out before it even gets to the (@OpCoordClass) parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you actually want so I am assuming a few things here.

- I assumed that `[Operations Class Code]` is a field that only contain either `True` or `False` or is a bit type (0 or 1)
- I assume that your parameter values match the field content.

Let's say that `[Operations Class Code]` is a bit or integer type and contains either a 0 or 1.

You parameter values would be

| Label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| True | 1 |
| False | 0 |

Your WHERE clause would then be extended by add

```
AND ([Operations Class Code] = @myParameter OR @myParameter = 0)
```

If the parameter is True (Value = 1) then only rows that match will be returned, if the parameter if False (Value = 0 ) then all rows will be returned.

If this does not help then please show a few sample rows of data and then show what you expect to be shown depending on what the parameter is set to.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

The False value works but the true value only shows data that has [Operations Class Code] I would like to add it with the rest of the data. 

I'll make a separate comment and show some sample rows of data

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the sample data and expected results there rather than using a comment.